# Problem with substance look and feel

Tags: java, swing, swingx, substance

I have downloaded the recent library by substance and i have downloaded the addons also for supporting SwingX components. I am still getting the following error when i run my application

```
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for:   org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneContainer[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,bord  er=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]  
java.lang.Error  
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:711)  
        at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:133)  
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:741)  
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1017)  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.LookAndFeelAddons.getUI(LookAndFeelAddons.java:308)  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneContainer.updateUI(JXTaskPaneContainer.java:141)  
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:69)  
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:78)  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXPanel.<init>(JXPanel.java:133)  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneContainer.<init>(JXTaskPaneContainer.java:113)  
        at operator.table_browser.initComponents(table_browser.java:48)  
        at operator.table_browser.<init>(table_browser.java:33)  
        at forms_helper.form_objects.<clinit>(form_objects.java:71)  
        at Main$1.run(Main.java:53)  
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)  
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)  
        at   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)  
        at   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)  
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  
        at Main$1.run(Main.java:53)  
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)  
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)  
        at   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)  
        at   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)  
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.LookAndFeelAddons.getUI(LookAndFeelAddons.java:313)  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneContainer.updateUI(JXTaskPaneContainer.java:141)  
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:69)  
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:78)  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXPanel.<init>(JXPanel.java:133)  
        at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneContainer.<init>(JXTaskPaneContainer.java:113)  
        at operator.table_browser.initComponents(table_browser.java:48)  
        at operator.table_browser.<init>(table_browser.java:33)  
        at forms_helper.form_objects.<clinit>(form_objects.java:71)  
        ... 9 more
```

Help me to solve this problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!!

I got that problem solved by just resetting the NetBeans cache files :) NetBeans is weird sometimes... had to go through some issue which is completely irrelevant.. :)

Answer (score 3):

1.st question are you added Substance L&F correctly on EDT

f.e.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceOfficeSilver2007LookAndFeel());
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i dont have this line added SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);

Comment: but i have adde the first line to include the LAF

Comment: :-) that's maybe only the start, be sure that that for this L&F you'll needed to update lots of *** correctly on EDT

Comment: is there anything else should do ?

Comment: if you'll use or already use some XxxRendered extends DefaultXxxRenderer, then you need change to extends SubstanceXxxRenderer, Renderer contents could be stay remained, but nobody know, I'm no expert for this L&F too, just tried it with intend just to remove some EDT issue ...., too :-)

Comment: You certainly do need the  invokeLater() method. But do you actually need the second line updateComponentTreeUI() if you create the frame afterwards? Did you get it from some resource which I could read? Thanks

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html  for Substance L&f inside Docs, but where is...